# Updating our help-center phrasing?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I think our [help-center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/) need some minor phrasing updates. Checking e.g. the "on-topic" page:

> - Android-independent ***phone*** questions, such as "Does Carrier X have prepaid plans?"

(emphasis mine), we should have "phone" replaced by "device" in most cases. Tablets are around for quite a while now, and even smart watches are running Android. Above example could lead to the conclusion that "Android independent *tablet* questions" are OK :)

While on this, and again with the current example, I'd even suggest checking the examples given, to make it more clear. IMHO "Android independent" doesn't only refer to carrier plans, but also to device-hardware things, like "what kind of GPS chip is built into X".

Comment: I s/phone/device/ and wait for more input in form of answers regarding the example questions.

Comment: Shall we open separate questions for each area? And if so, per page or pare question on the page?

Comment: Does it need "phone" or "device"? Could it just be *"Android-independent questions"*?

Comment: Good point. Removed 'device'.

Comment: @Flow Thanks! Then this Q can be marked "completed" I guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed to just "Android-independent questions".